# prevent the name of model.matrix to appear in the results on a regression

Tags: r, interaction, model.matrix

Is it possible to use model matrix in a regression without having the name of the model matrix in the regression results?

I need to go through such a procedure as I have some interactions for which I have no observation. (i.e) the results of the interaction is `NA`.

A related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462289/forcing-a-reference-category-in-logistic-model-in-r/24106473#24106473).

Here are some data to illustrate my point:

```
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
str(mydata)

gre_ <- mydata$gre-mean(mydata$gre)

a <- model.matrix(~-1+gre_:factor(rank),data=mydata)[,-c(2)]

summary(glm(admit~gpa+gre+factor(rank)+a,data=mydata, family=binomial))
```

results

```
Call:
glm(formula = admit ~ gpa + gre + rank + a, family = binomial, 
data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6449  -0.8886  -0.6332   1.1706   2.1949  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -3.0039781  1.4012928  -2.144   0.0321 *  
gpa                  0.7634679  0.3297215   2.315   0.0206 *  
gre                  0.0016098  0.0016634   0.968   0.3332    
rank                -0.5584921  0.1288588  -4.334 1.46e-05 ***
agre_:factor(rank)1  0.0014010  0.0028001   0.500   0.6168    
agre_:factor(rank)3  0.0010074  0.0025007   0.403   0.6871    
agre_:factor(rank)4  0.0009936  0.0034111   0.291   0.7708    
---
```

How do we get rid of the `model.matrix` name *a* in the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run with this formula syntax, R is going to put the "a" there. You can extract the names of coefficients and remove the first "a" if you like with `gsub()` or use `substr()` to remove the first letter. It depends on how you want to process them down the line.

The other option is to use `glm.fit` and specify the complete model matrix yourself. Something like

```
a <- model.matrix(~-1+gre_:factor(rank),data=mydata)[,-c(2)]
b <- model.matrix(~gpa+gre+rank, data=mydata)
mm<-cbind(b,a)

ff<-glm.fit(mm,mydata$admit, family=binomial())
class(ff)<-c("glm","lm")
summary(ff)
```

will return

```
Call:
NULL

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6449  -0.8886  -0.6332   1.1706   2.1949  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        -3.0039781  1.4012928  -2.144   0.0321 *  
gpa                 0.7634679  0.3297215   2.315   0.0206 *  
gre                 0.0016098  0.0016634   0.968   0.3332    
rank               -0.5584921  0.1288588  -4.334 1.46e-05 ***
gre_:factor(rank)1  0.0014010  0.0028001   0.500   0.6168    
gre_:factor(rank)3  0.0010074  0.0025007   0.403   0.6871    
gre_:factor(rank)4  0.0009936  0.0034111   0.291   0.7708    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 499.98  on 399  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 459.13  on 393  degrees of freedom
AIC: 473.13

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Here your estimates are the same and your variable names are untouched. Since its not technically a real `glm` object we are fibbing a bit by adding the class information, but it does have nearly all the same properties (you can see the "call" is missing) and in most cases should behave like a regular `glm` object with most functions, including `summary()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It let me to a place I didn't expect though. is it possbile to pass the solution to glm?. My ultimate goal is to use the effects package. as effect("gre_:factor(rank)1",test); But is throws an error.`Error in terms.default(model) : no terms component nor attribute`

Comment: If you're going to muck about with the design matrix like this, the "terms" are no longer representative of the model. Why are you doing this again? You can some groups are missing? It should be fine to leave those in the model and R just won't be able to estimate them. And why are you sometimes treating rank both as numeric and categorical. That seems unusual.

Comment: The numeric rank was a typo and my first comment is irrelevant. I was just thinking that it might have been interesting to keep all the properties of the glm. But I guess one have to choose. Thanks